# Eigenvector of matrix of equal numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For matrix the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
3&1&1\\
1&3&1\\
1&1&3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=5$, $\lambda_2=2$, $\lambda_3=2$, I am trying to find the corresponding eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 2. I got

$$(A - 2I_3) = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Reducing it (row reduced echelon form), I get:

$$\left[
\begin{array}
{ccc|c}
1&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right]$$

Ending up with $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$. How would I find the eigenvector from there? Usually, I end up getting two equations and it's easy from there. How would you do it with one?

Comment: For instance, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are free, but $x_1=-x_2-x_3$. This is two-dimensional. A basis is $(1,-1,0)$ and $(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: So to make it in terms of $x_1$, you set $x_1$ to 1 and set once $x_2$ to zero, and in the other vector, $x_3$ to zero (the other would be -1 as the equation $x_1 = -x_2-x_3$ shows)?

Comment: Not really. Say $x_2=s$ and $x_3=t$ are free. Then $x_1=-x_2-x_3=-s-t$. So $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-s-t,s,t)=s(-1,1,0)+t(-1,0,1)$. This proves that the solution set is spanned by the latter two vectors. As they are independent, they constitute a basis. Of the eigenspace.

Comment: I still don't get how you got (-1, 1, 0) and (-1, 0, -1). I know it's the right answer, but I how do you get it from x1+x2+x3 = 0?

Answer (score 3):

For any square matrix with one value on the diagonal and another value everywhere else, a consistent pattern of (orthogonal) eigenvectors for the $n$ by $n$ case can be read from the columns of
$$    
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  7  &  -1  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  8  &  -1   \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  9   
\end{array}
  \right).
  $$
In your case, the upper left 3 by 3 corner. If you want the result orthonormal you need to divide each column by a square root of something appropriate. I have displayed the  10 by 10 version, notice how the diagonal numbers go up to 9 = 10 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have a two-dimensional eigenspace, so there should be two linearly independent eigenvectors, that each satisfy $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ for you to choose.

More details: Every eigenvalue has an associated eigenspace.  The dimension of this eigenspace is called the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue, while the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial is called the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue.  These two constants satisfy $1\le GM(\lambda)\le AM(\lambda)$.  For the problem at hand, $\lambda=2$, and $GM(\lambda)=AM(\lambda)=2$.  The eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=2$ is a two-dimensional vector space.  Every vector in it satisfies $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$.  What you're trying to find is a basis for this vector space.  @Julien gave an example in the comments above of such a basis, but it's not unique.  Any two linearly independent vectors that satisfy the equation will serve as a basis.  For example, $(3,-1,-2)$ and $(5,-10,5)$.

Comment: I know. This matrix has 3 eigenvalues, two of which are repeated, so I can generate the third from the second. But how would I find the second? (I already found the first corresponding to the single real-valued eigenvalue). This does not answer how to find it.

Comment: I understand all of this. I still don't get how you'd get to (-1, 1, 0) and (-1, 0, -1) from $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$

Comment: It's arbitrary.  How do you find a solution to $x_1+x_2=0$?  You can pick $(1,-1)$ or $(3,-3)$ or $(-4,4)$.