# Positive definiteness of the following matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, positive-definite

We have the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
I learned the terms positive definiteness and signature only recently, so I would really appreciate it if somebody could show me if this matrix if positive definite and what its rank and signature are. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Can somebody show me how to compute the rank and signature of this matrix specifically?

Comment: check the eigenvalues of it

Comment: you could see a process at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380825/how-do-you-orthogonally-diagonalize-the-matrix

Answer (score 3):

By [Silvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if all of the leading principal minors have positive determinant. 
Since the $2\times 2$ principal minor has determinant zero, the matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: And how would you determine the rank and signature?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988814/determine-signature-of-matrix).

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is positive definite if it's determinant is positive. In this matrix the determinant is negative so the matrix is not positive definite.

Signature: Since the determinant is negative, so this matrix has atmost one negative eigenvalue.

Rank: Rank is equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues (counting multiplicity)

Comment: In fact, all determinants of the leading principal minors must be positive, in particular the determinant. But the determinant of a $2\times 2$-matrix is easier to compute.

Comment: A matrix is positive definite if all its eigenvalues are positive. Any matrix with an even number of negative eigenvalues will have a positive determinant.

Comment: You both are correct. @JessicaK

Comment: It is obvious that $1$ is an eigenvalue of this matrix. This is not negative definite.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option how to decide on the definiteness of the matrix simply by definition. Since $[1,-1,1]A[1,-1,1]^T=-1<0$ and $[1,1,1]A[1,1,1]^T=7>0$, the matrix is indefinite.

Answer (score 0):

Call your matrix $A$. It has at least one positive eigenvalue because its trace is positive. It follows that $A$ has exactly one negative eigenvalue and two positive eigenvalues because $\det A<0$. Hence $A$ is not positive definite and it has full rank.