# How to find the determinant of a NxN matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Here is my matrix. How do I find the determinant of this one? I'm really trying to solve it but I can't think of anything.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2& ...& 2\\ 2& 3& ...& 2\\ 2& 2& 3& ...\\ 2& 2& ...& 3 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: asked many times, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375711/eigenvector-of-matrix-of-equal-numbers for example. Nevertheless, i suggest you calculate the $n$ by $n$ determinant for $n=1,2,3.$ Not hard

Comment: That's the first thing I would do but I thought it wouldn't work for any number.

Comment: Please do $n=1,2,3$ anyway. Call it "hands-on experience." A few cases is not a proof, but it is more than you currently know, and the practice really will help.

Comment: Alright I will try it now, thank you. Should I do it for X in the place of 3 and Y in the place of 2 for a more general approach?

Comment: I suggest $3,2$ first.

Comment: It's $2n+1$ right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: I feel stupid for not doing that sooner.

Comment: You are not alone thinking so:)

Comment: See here for a generalization: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Try to show that it is equal $5+2(n-2)$ using this.
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2& ...& 2\\ 2& 3& ...& 2\\ 2& 2& 3& ...\\ 2& 2& ...& 3 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1& 0&...& 0\\ 0& 1& -1& ...& 0\\ 0& 0& 1& ... &0\\ 2& 2& 2&...& 3 \end{vmatrix}
$$